# Horizontal scrolling div not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scroll

I have a scrolling div contain a `ul` in react.
When the number of `li`increased, the division should scroll horizontally.

this is my code:

```
<div className="inner-scrolling">
  <ul className="list">
     <li> item</li>
     ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

this is css:

```
.inner-scrolling {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

This is working correctly in Chrome but not working in Firefox. How can I fix it?
I tried `max-width:500px` but it doesn't work in Firefox yet. actually in Firefox, `li`s move out of the `div`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add `display: flex`, `overflow-y: hidden` and `overflow-x: scroll` to the `<ul>` container.

You will also need extra containers for it to be able to work in Firefox and Safari.

All the child elements will be in a row, horizontally scrollable.

#### Snippet:

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.scrolling-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  max-height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scrolling-container">
      <div class="list">
        <img src="https://www.cowgirlcontractcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/360/2018/05/placeholder-img.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="https://www.cowgirlcontractcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/360/2018/05/placeholder-img.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="https://www.cowgirlcontractcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/360/2018/05/placeholder-img.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="https://www.cowgirlcontractcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/360/2018/05/placeholder-img.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="https://www.cowgirlcontractcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/360/2018/05/placeholder-img.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="https://www.cowgirlcontractcleaning.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/360/2018/05/placeholder-img.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the point was :
adding `display: flex, overflow-y: hidden and overflow-x: scroll` to the `<ul>` container.
 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code. There are multiple corrections/additions I have done in the code below.

```
.outerDiv {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner-scrolling {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: flex;
}
.list {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.list li {
    width: 100px; /* Temporary width is given you can remove it later on. */
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="inner-scrolling">
        <ul class="list">
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
            <li>item 5</li>
            <li>item 6</li>
            <li>item 7</li>
            <li>item 8</li>
            <li>item 9</li>
            <li>item 10</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code works separately but unfortunately doesn't work for me in my case.
In addition,it doesn't need to the `outerDiv` at all and works without it. Thank you