# CSS - grid overflow scrool doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, grid, overflow

I am not a CSS specjalist. I have some CSS code which is working on Chrome and Brave, but not on Firefox. How to change that code, to make it universal:

```
.grid-table {
    display: grid;
    height: 95%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

In Firefox `overflow-x: scroll` doesn't work and content extends beyond the div.

Thanks for a help!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445681/horizontal-scrolling-div-not-working-in-firefox) answer your question?

Comment: Not really, I do not want to change styling display to flex, it would need to much changes in my project.